# Declare Connection Variable

Tags: c#, java, php, c++

I want to know which is safe & better way to use Connection variable of following.

First : Connection as class member variable of class

```
class MyClass
{
    Connection conn;

    public MyClass(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        //Do some DB operations using conn
    }
}
```

Second : Initialize connection in method

```
class MyClass
{       
    public MyClass() {      
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        Connection conn= initializeFunction(); //Initialize Connection
        //Do some DB operations using conn
    }
}
```

Third : Send connection as argument to function

```
class MyClass
{       
    public MyClass() {      
    }

    public void myMethod(Connection conn){
        //Do some DB operations using conn
    }
}
```

NOTE : Question is not programming language specific, hence I have added tags other than Java as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to Database Connection object, the best is: **To open as late as possible and close as early as possible**.

In C# there is a `using` statement which works with objects implementing IDisposable interface. `using` statement works like try/finally block of code. IMO the general practice for handling connection should be something like:

```
try
{
connection = new Connection();
connection.Open(); // open the connection
//work with the connection, DB CRUD operations
}
finally
{
if(connection != null)
     connection.Close(); // close the connection in finally block
                         // so that even if the exception occurs, connection gets closed. 
}
```

For your options, I believe the first one is the worst, which holds the connetion object along with the object of the class.

I think you **should be more concerned about opening/closing the connection** rather than holding the object of the connection in multiple places.

Answer (score 6):

All three approaches provide different functionality:

1. Your class owns the connection object and the connection object will stay alive as long as your object stays alive.
2. The connection object is local to the method and expires once the method returns.
3. The caller of the method owns the connection object.

The choice depends on:

- How do you want to handle the **ownership** of the connection object &
- You need to bear in mind that the DB connection needs to be open only as long as required and not all the time, while also,
- How frequently would you want to connect to the database.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to use `Connection` is always to declare `Connection` inside `using` statement:

```
using (var connection = InitializeConnection())
{
}
```

It will handle to close connection automatically even exceptions throw out.

Luckily, behind the scene ADO.NET use *Connection Pool* to manage and optimize connections to database for you automatically, so you don't need to care much how many connections open in your application. They are just *logical connections*.

Don't just keep connection long because it will slow the performance and does not make use of parallel access of connection pool

Answer (score 3):

I would go for option 1 or 3, depending on the requirement.

- I would choose option 1 if there are more methods then the one defined using the connection. With method 1 it is easy to use **Dependency Injection** and **Inversion of Control**.
- I would choose option 3 if that method on my class was the only method using the connection.

Method 2 is difficult to test, because there is no way you can define a **mock** object for the connection.

Furthermore, I would suggest not passing a *type* but a **Interface** to `MyClass`.

Comment: `I would suggest not passing a type but a Interface to MyClass` can you pls explain more on it.

Answer (score 3):

This would depend on if you want to provide the ability of modifying the Connection object outside of the method.

Personally I would go with Option 1 or 2.  `Option 1` if MyClass is a Database container with multiple methods associated with it, i.e. Connecting to a database, SharePoint, Running Stored Procedures etc.  `Option 2`, if the Connection object was only used for a short duration, i.e. Opening a connection and processing the data elsewhere. `Option 3`, I would not prefer passing a Connection object to a method but this is just personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred solution entirely depends on the programming environment. What is true for Java or any other long running processes, is wrong for PHP and similar per-request execution.

In Java you usually have a DB connection pool to use, which is there to limit the number of concurrent connections to the database because most of the time they are idle. On average, you don't need as many connections as there are queries in the code. But on the other hand, it would be a waste of time if you would connect to the database only as the first query has to be executed. Java programms are constantly running, why not opening an appropriate number of DB connections on statup? Then they are ready when they are needed.

In PHP, when a script ends, everything is forgotten and deleted in memory. There simply is no place to store an active ongoing DB connection. So the best approach is to connect to the database at the very moment you know for sure that you must send a query. On the other hand, I would disagree with 'closing it as early as possible' in PHP because it will be closed when the script ends, which is reasonably soon enough. Prematurely closing the connection might mean that you have to reopen it for another query.

I would also object to the idea of singletons for the DB connection in PHP (Java might be a different game). Yes, you normally would have only one database, but what if not? Singletons prevent you from using two databases, don't start with it. mysqli_connect() uses an existing connection if you use the same connection parameters (server, username, password) and acts like a singleton for you, so there is no need to do it again in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose the second option, with a minor modification. I would change the call to the `initializeFunction()` to a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object, which would yield a connection. You will then close it the moment you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your connection is going to be used by many mthods. I would recomment opening and closing it as quick as possible so option2 would be best for me. Just use the connection when you need it. You might also be interested in the [c3po](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) library for pooling your connections.

Generally if I am delcring variables that are used elsewhere in the class I would use option1 and made the Connection final. As this is a db connection I think the rules change slightly though.